# Error "ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib" ios

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have an `xcode` project which was created by `unity` , now when i am trying to run on iphone 6 it is giving error ,

```
ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**screenshot** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFfUU.png)

please help